# Issue with NA in conditionals in for-loop

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have the following dataset:

```
date <- as.Date(c('2010-11-1','2010-11-2','2010-11-3','2010-11-4','2010-11-5','2010-11-6','2010-11-7','2010-11-8','2010-11-9','2010-11-10'))
precipitation <- c(0, 11, NA,3,0,0,13,7,9,10)
snowheight <- c(5,7,56,32, 11, 24, NA,8, 13, 11)
temperature <- c(-5, -2, 0, 0.4, NA, 5,6,4, 9, 10)

df <- data.frame(date, precipitation, snowheight, temperature)
```

I am trying to create a dichotomous variable with (0 and 1) for each datasample based on the following conditions:

- if snowheight > 10 we continue with the conditions below. Else assign NA to the dichotomous variable.
- if precipitation =< 0 we assign 0
- if precipitation > 0 and temperature > 0 we assign 1.
- if precipitation > 0 and temperature < 0 we assign 0.
- if one of the conditional variable contains NA, NA should be assigned to the dichtomous variable as well.

Here is the desired output:

```
date precipitation snowheight temperature dicht
1  2010-11-01             0          5        -5.0    NA
2  2010-11-02            11          7        -2.0    NA
3  2010-11-03            NA         56         0.0    NA
4  2010-11-04             3         32         0.4     1
5  2010-11-05             0         11          NA    NA
6  2010-11-06             0         24         5.0     0
7  2010-11-07            13         NA         6.0    NA
8  2010-11-08             7          8         4.0    NA
9  2010-11-09             9         13         9.0     1
10 2010-11-10            10         11        10.0     1
```

I have the following loop that works fine if there is no NA in the data:

```
for (i in seq_len(nrow(df))){
  if (df$snowheight[i] > 10){
    if (df$precipitation[i] > 0){
      if (df$temperature[i]> 0){
        df$dicht[i] <- 1
      } else {
        df$dicht[i] <- 0
      }
    } else {
      df$dicht[i] <- 0
    }
  } else {
    df$dicht[i] <- NA
  }
}
```

However, since my data contains NA, I get the following error:

```
Error in if (df$precipitation[i] > 0) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

I tried this solution but I get the same error:

```
for(i in seq_len(nrow(df))){
  if (is.na(df$snowheight[i])){
    df$dicht[i] <- NA
  } else if (df$snowheight[i] > 10){
    if(df$precipitation[i] > 0){
      if(df$temperature[i]> 0){
        df$dicht[i] <- 1
      } else {
        df$dicht[i] <- 0
      }
    } else {
      df$dicht[i] <- 0
    }
  } else {
    df$dicht[i] <- NA
  }
  if (is.na(df$precipitation[i])){
    df$dicht[i] <- NA
  }
  if (is.na(df$temperature[i])){
    df$dicht[i] <- NA
  }
}
```

Hope you can help. Let me know if you need more info. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if/else` is not vectorized.   We can use `case_when` with first condition that checks for 'snowheight' value less than or equal to 10 and assign it to `NA`, then we do the other checks (where implicitly it would be 'snowheight' greater than 10)

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   mutate(dicht = case_when(is.na(snowheight)|is.na(precipitation)|
            is.na(temperature)|snowheight <=10 ~ NA_real_, 
            precipitation <= 0 ~ 0, 
            precipitation > 0 & temperature  > 0 ~ 1, 
            precipitation > 0 & temperature  < 0 ~ 0))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, this is not working as desired. This would work perfectly if my data didn't contain NA. The "dicht" variable should automatically be assigned NA if some of the other variables (precipitation, snowheight or temperature) have NA.

Comment: @ZorinIvanov When you have NA in any of those variables.  What should be the output expecetd

Comment: Okay so lets look at a single row as an example:
Let's say we have snowheight > 10, precipitation > 0 but temperature is NA. Dicht should also be assigned NA (missing value) because some of the variables have missing value.
Let's say precipitation is > 0, temperature is > 0 but snowheight is NA, then again dicht should be NA. And the same goes for all variables. If they contain a missing value, I should assign a missing value in the dicht variable as well. Besides that, dicht should be assigned missing value if snowheight is below 10. For all other cases the conditions are explained.

Comment: Short answer to your question:  The expected output in the "dicht" variable should be NA

Comment: @ZorinIvanov if you can update your post with the expected output column 'dicht', it may be easier to crosscheck

Comment: @ZorinIvanov i updated the code based on your comment.  But, it is always better to show the expected output so that it becomes more clear. thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot. I managed to get the desired result myself in the meantime but your solution works perfect as well. I will still update the desired output just in case this thread might be helpful for someone.